# Matlab - extracting streamline data

Tags: matlab

I have two velocity field in two directions. And I use `streamline(x,y,Vx,Vy,startx,starty)` to plot the corresponding streamline.

Is there anyway I can write this streamline data on to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [`stream2`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stream2.html) or [`stream3`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stream3.html) to generate streamline data, instead of plotting it.

Then just save it with any standard saving function that you desire